# CookieContainer ошибка

Tags: c#, cookie

Есть код. Хочу достать cookies с webbrowser1. Пишет ошибку:

> Необработанное исключение типа "System.Net.CookieException" в
>   System.dll Дополнительные сведения: Недопустимая часть
>   "Value"="7200,0" файла cookie.

Что я делаю не так???

```
public CookieContainer GetCookieContainer()
    {
        CookieContainer container = new CookieContainer();

        foreach (string cookie in webBrowser1.Document.Cookie.Split(';'))
        {
            string name = cookie.Split('=')[0];
            string value = cookie.Substring(name.Length + 1);
            string path = "/";
            string domain = ".steamcommunity.com"; //change to your domain name
            container.Add(new System.Net.Cookie(name.Trim(), value.Trim(), path, domain));
        }

        return container;
    }
```

Сами куки 
`_ga=GA1.2.1317698739.1478508335; timezoneOffset=7200,0; sessionid=15c54f90d07c675352504989; steamCountry=UA%7Cd0fdd0d7b615e7c0200338daca9e4cc4`

Дописал `value = Regex.Replace(value, ",", ".");`, но оно не пашет. Хотя куки передает с функции. Я что то зецепил когда исправил 7200,0 на 7200.0???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вот [тут](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/kesbe27x(v=vs.110).aspx) детально обьясняется почему у вас выпало исключение. Цитата:

> Следующие символы зарезервированы и не могут быть переданы в value параметр, если строка, передаваемая в value параметр заключен в двойные кавычки: точка с запятой, запятая.

Ваша проблема решаеться очень просто

```
public CookieContainer GetCookieContainer()
{
    CookieContainer container = new CookieContainer();

    foreach (string cookie in webBrowser1.Document.Cookie.Split(';'))
    {
        string name = cookie.Split('=')[0];
        string value = cookie.Substring(name.Length + 1);
        string path = "/";
        string domain = ".steamcommunity.com"; //change to your domain name
        container.Add(new System.Net.Cookie(name.Trim(), @value.Trim(), path, domain));
    }

    return container;
}
```